# Creating a new mongodb database using revel framework in golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, revel

I am trying to create a new database in mongodb using revel framework and mgo driver. Here's my code in --> src/myapp/app/db/mgo.go

```
package db

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

var Session *mgo.Session
var Users   *mgo.Collection

func Init(url, dbname string) {

    var err error
    Session,err = mgo.Dial(url)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    Session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    Users = Session.DB(dbname).C("users")
}
```

and here's the code from where the program runs --> src/myapp/app/controllers/app.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "myapp/app/db"
)

type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c App) Hello() revel.Result{

    db.Init("127.0.0.1", "mydb")
    return c.Render()
}
```

The problem is I am not able to create a database by these two parts of separate files of code, whereas when I merge them in one (i.e. just app.go) then it works well. Here's the code that works in --> src/myapp/app/controllers/app.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c App) Hello() revel.Result{

    session,err:=mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer session.Close()

    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    d:=session.DB("mydb").C("anydata")
    return c.Render()
}
```

So I would like someone to help me in correcting my first two parts of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have access to `db.Session` and `db.Users` from controllers/app.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "myapp/app/db"
 )

type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func init() {
    db.Init("127.0.0.1", "mydb")
}

func (c App) Hello() revel.Result{


    //there use db
    db.Session.Find(...)
    return c.Render()
}
```